# duplicate symbol _DEBUG_SWITCHER in

Tags: ios, duplicates, symbols

When I used libMTKBleManager.a, the following error occurred at compile time, which is the only static library in my project, and when I set the Build Configuration to the release, compile success. Why?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVex3.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your build phases, check to see that you aren't compiling the same file more than once.try to remove  and add again.

Comment: I've tried to re-add, but it's still wrong, and this happens when I use cocopoads, and if I build a new project and I add libMTKBleManager. A to build the project, I don't get it wrong

Comment: remove libMTJBleManger from build phases and build.

Comment: I can't remove libMTKBleManager